# printw() and mvwprintw() do not print

Tags: c, ncurses

I am trying to test both printw and mvwprintw by printing a string at each new line. However they do not print anything.

This is the output on the terminal:

```
gcc -c -g *.c
gcc *.o -o main.exe -lncurses
DBOJANTC-M-KDD5:ncursestest user22$ main.exe
DBOJANTC-M-KDD5:ncursestest user22$
```

How do I make these functions print on the screen or window?

```
    int main() {

        char stuff[25] = "stuffstuff\n";
        int rows = 7;

        WINDOW* win;
        //int delwin(WINDOW *win);

        //printf("dddd\n");

        initscr();
        raw();
        noecho();
        printw("Try resizing your window(if possible) and then run this program again");
        win = newwin(rows, 80,  0, 0);


        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){

            mvwprintw(win, i, 0,"%s", stuff);

            wrefresh(win);
        }

    endwin();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the return value of the print? Make sure it's not `ERR`.

Answer (score 2):

`printw` and `mvwprintw` are actually printing. 
It is just that you are immediately refreshing the window or closing the window, thus you are not able to see the prints.

Try adding `getch` before closing or refreshing the window.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){

        mvwprintw(win, i, 0,"%s", stuff);
        getch();  //here
        wrefresh(win);
    }
getch();  //here
endwin();
```

Or even you can use `sleep`.

Comment: I can see the output now, but is there a way to make it visible without having to input  during runtime?

Comment: You can use `sleep`.

Comment: Using sleep, I cannot see the output without a huge delay. With a small delay nothing is printed

Comment: kiran, @a.boj: refresh does not mean clear. It is the refresh call which causes the library to show the output. The call to sleep should go *after* the refresh. Getch works because getch automatically calls refresh before waiting for input. See the ncurses manpages.

Comment: Even after I put sleep after refresh, nothing is printed. Also the ncurses manual does not mention anything about sleep.

Comment: @A.boj, well, the ncurses manual does not mention `exit(2)` nor `sin(3)` also.  `sleep(3)` makes the process to sleep for a number of seconds... so it's strange you don't get the output if you embed a `sleep(3)` at some part. A library is a collection of routines to be used in a program with some other routines also.  Neither curses nor `sleep(3)` manual pages say the other cannot be used with it.